# Show YouTube private videoes only for website users

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I have experience with YouTube API. But I always used it for public videos. Now. what I want to achieve is, to make video on my YouTube channel TOTALLY invisible (in other word private) and shows this video only to website users.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: host it on your own server then.

Answer (score 9):

This is from the [Google's Productforums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/Tm6Vceo_tc4/zo50aawqnLwJ)

> For clarification. Yes, you can embed private videos. However, it really isn't feasible to do so since YouTube's private videos require that the viewer have a YouTube account, be signed into that account and have that account added to the video's access list. They are limited to 50 people.
>   You can embed unlisted videos, they don't have the same authentication restrictions as private videos. However, all that is necessary to view an unlisted video to know the URL. If your website is crawled by search engines, the unlisted video may as well be public.

You may want to look into self-hosting your own videos to have better control and to be sure that you aren't violating YouTube's Terms of Service (which prohibits some uses of the embedded player).

Vimeo.com also has more robust access controls and can only allow the video to be embedded on a specific domain. However, they don't allow commercial use...so that may be a catch if that applies to you.

Comment: My servers is not able to stream tonss of video. So I want to use youtube as stream server

Comment: i would like others to pay for may bandwidth and storage usage to.

Comment: Vimeo allows commercial use, you just have to pay $199/year. Which is a great deal...

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work. YouTube video > Edit Video > Video Details > ⫶ > Share Privately. Then the key for me was to remember to edit the visibility of the playlist to be Unlisted rather than Private. In other words, I don't think Private playlists are shareable, but you can set the visibility to each video to Private (and grant access to certain email addresses) and then wrap them in a playlist with Unlisted visibility.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting the video to `private`, set it to `unlisted`. It won't appear in any listing on youtube, i.e. your channel, search results & related videos but you can link to it and embed it like a normal video.

Comment: This just does not seem like a scalable solution for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Youtube Provide 3 kinds video permission.

1. Public ---- Open for all
2. Unlisted --- Can watch video by embed / shared link only,, but not in youtube search / undel channel.
3. Private -- own and selected people.