# How to display the Private Videos of my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api

How do you display  private videos from my YouTube channel to my own Website.
Thank you

Comment: I think this link might answer your question.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519374/show-youtube-private-videoes-only-for-website-users

Comment: but you can link to it and embed it like a normal video. (unlisted video)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the video to private, set it to unlisted. It won't appear in any listing on youtube, i.e. your channel, search results & related videos but you can link to it and embed it like a normal video.

Comment: and can be read from a youtube page by his id? as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx

Comment: I do not want the video to be seen from youtube. Thanks