# Embed a youtube playlist in a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube

Without using the Youtube API, is there a way to get a playlist embedded in your webpage?

I know for a single video you would do something like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%#Eval("MyLinkField")%>?rel=0"></iframe>
```

where MyLinkField would be the 11-character ID that youtube uses for each video.

I can't figure out how to get a playlist to embed in a webpage.

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en should help you

Comment: I'm not 100% sure then link above is still valid. The share button that it refers to is not available for playlists

Comment: Here is an active link to the docs: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en But I can't seem to successfully embed a playlist of private videos, which https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519445/470749 implies I should be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLAYLIST_ID"></iframe>
```

Where `PLAYLIST_ID` is the id from the querystring when viewing the playlist:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/71q4pe8v/